# Remove entire [$key] from array stored in custom field using Ajax - unset($array[$key]); not working

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, ajax

I'm looking to use Ajax to delete the key `[1]` from the following array which is stored in a custom user field and then re-save it...

I am trying to do this by using `unset($array[$key])` then saving the updated values but without any success I'm afraid.

TYI for your help...

```
Array (

  [0] => Array (
    [dna_cal_when] => 1576926000
    [dna_cal_position_id] => 
    [dna_cal_candidate_id] => 
  )

  [1] => Array (
    [dna_cal_when] => 1576927800
    [dna_cal_position_id] => 
    [dna_cal_candidate_id] => 
  )

  [2] => Array (
    [dna_cal_when] => 1576929600
    [dna_cal_position_id] => 
    [dna_cal_candidate_id] => 
  )

)
```

**Here is the function...**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dna_nuke_diary_slots', 'dna_nuke_diary_slots' );

function dna_nuke_diary_slots() {

  $user   = $_POST['user']; 
  $stamp  = array($_POST['stamp']);

  // values for these two variables are retrieved from custom data attribute in following html and ajax call

  $stamps = !empty(get_user_meta( $user, 'dna_cal', true)) ? get_user_meta( $user, 'dna_cal', true) : array();
  $key    = array_search($stamp, array_column($stamps, 'dna_cal_when'));

  unset($stamps[$key]);

  $new_stamps   = $stamps;
  $sort_stamps  = array_values($new_stamps);

  update_user_meta( $user, 'dna_cal', $sort_stamps);

  wp_die();

}
```

**FYI - following is the Ajax call and a sample of the HTML**

```
$('.slot').on('click', 'a.booked', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var user   = $('#dna_day').attr( 'data-user' );
  var stamp  = $(this).attr( 'data-timestamp' );

  $(this).removeClass('booked').addClass('nuked');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      action: 'dna_nuke_diary_slots',
      user: user,
      stamp: stamp
    }
  });

});


<div id="dna_day" class="dna-day" data-user="256">
  <div id="dna_slots" class="slots">
    <div class="slot"><a class="booked" data-timestamp="1576926000" href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="slot"><a class="booked" data-timestamp="1576927800" href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="slot"><a class="booked" data-timestamp="1576929600" href="#"></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you do a `print_r($stamps);` and a `print_r($key);` and post the results? Both before the unset

Comment: Thank you Cornel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can not unset key because you can not find proper key from array. The issue is that you did `$stamp  = array($_POST['stamp']);` as array which is wrong. you have to remove `array()` from `$stamp`, so which look like `$stamp  = $_POST['stamp'];`. then you can search value in column from array and unset it. I have tested below code which is working properly.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dna_nuke_diary_slots', 'dna_nuke_diary_slots' );

function dna_nuke_diary_slots() {

  $user   = $_POST['user']; 
  $stamp  = $_POST['stamp']; // here you have to remove array();

  // values for these two variables are retrieved from custom data attribute in following html and ajax call
  $stamps = !empty(get_user_meta( $user, 'dna_cal', true)) ? get_user_meta( $user, 'dna_cal', true) : array();

  $key    = array_search($stamp, array_column($stamps, 'dna_cal_when'));

  unset($stamps[$key]);

  $new_stamps   = $stamps;
  $sort_stamps  = array_values($new_stamps);

  update_user_meta( $user, 'dna_cal', $sort_stamps);

  wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner! Thank you Chetan :)